# Aggregation.match() is not working when searching id

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am having some weird problem in `spring-data-mongo`.

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(id));
List<Hotel> hotels = mongoOperations.find(query, Hotel.class)
```

giving correct result (`findById`).

However,

```
MatchOperation match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("id").is(id));
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(match);
AggregationResults<Hotel> results = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, "hotel", Hotel.class);
```

is giving `[]` every time.

Is there anything I am missing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer :

```
Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("_id").is(new ObjectId(hotelId)));
```